Accidentally consumed alcohol by sharing food
I went to a Cafe with my friends they ate tiramesu there I didn't even touch the utensils near it as I knew there was alcohol in it and also I did not know the cafe had alcohol otherwise I wouldn't have went there so My friends ate the food and I ordered hot chocolate My friends took a sip from it and I took a sip from it but I completely forgot that they had consumed something that had alcohol in it.
What is the punishment I will get for such a big mistake and how can ask for forgiveness

No one can avoid such small quantities of alcohol.

@UmH did you even think about if what maham tells is really a sin? I don't think it is (based on 5|91, sorry I don't know how to reference Quranic verses, so I do it the way in the text), and I feel you did not consider if she even sinned or not.

What I have found in the English translations of the written Quran is:

5|91|Shaitan (Satan) wants only to excite enmity and hatred between
you with intoxicants (alcoholic drinks) and gambling, and hinder you
from the remembrance of Allah and from As-Salat (the prayer). So, will
you not then abstain?

And what I read from it is that you should avoid intoxication, and you were far from that.
And as a second thought, maybe Shaitan has switched tactics and makes you intoxicated by fear?

This is from the Hilali translation. Other translations do not word it as "alcohol" but as "wine", but all I have seen take it as intoxicant. So I believe it does not refer to the chemical called ethanol but to everything that intoxicates humans.

I was not intoxicated didn't even touch the utensils or the food I just let them have sip of my hot chocolate but that means I might have accidentally consumed through the sharing of food alcohol. Will my prayers and will be accepted

@mahamzafar Quite obviously you could not get drunk by such a small amount of alcohol and according to the sura I cited, this is the main point for avoiding alcohol. You did not sin and have no reason to repent. May Allah guide you not to sin in other ways.
